# Setting a default value for empty json field

Tags: java, android, json

I have to parse a json whom a field can be empty:

```
{"fullField":"ok","canBeEmpty":""}
```

if I try to parse this string overall parsing fails with a "no value for canBeEmpty".
For each json item I execute:

```
json_data.getString("field"); //throws exception if empty
```

I'd like to still keep the parsing, setting the canBeEmpty value to a default string...is it possibile?

Comment: Are you sure that getString is throwing an exception?  It should only throw an exception if the field does not exist, not if the field value is empty - which is a perfectly valid value for a string.  I think you're problem is elsewhere.  Please post the relevant part of your parser.  I also don't see what "field" has to do with the example you've shown.

Comment: Ok, checking better I see that some field have "null" as value..I'm using isNull and everything's fine! @imrankhan if you want post as answer and I'll give you "correct" ;)

Comment: @Phate : Thanks Phate,you can check my answer !!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use  [JSONObject.JSONObject(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to check if any name is exist or not in json object as:

```
if(JSONObject.isNull("field")){
// do something here
}
else{
//do something here
}
```